# Passing variables to cfinclude

Tags: coldfusion

How can I pass a variable to a cfm page that I'm including from another page?

Example:

```
<cfset a.name = "me">
<cfset a.age = 135>
<cfinclude template="displayNameAndAgeFrom_A.cfm">
```

and displayNameAndAgeFrom_A.cfm is

```
<cfoutput>#a.name# #a.age#</cfoutput>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? Does it throw an error?

Comment: The code will work as it is, the included template shares the same variables scope as the including template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, this should work, exactly the way you posted it, without having to pass anything at all. Any values available in the outside/calling page are available in the included page.

Comment: Where I messed up was nesting the CFINCLUDE inside CFOUTPUT tags. The CFOUTPUT must go *inside* the CFINCLUDE.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting that you also have `<cfmodule ... />` available.  `cfmodule` will let you call the same template but you can pass in different values for the same attributes.

Check out [ColdFusion 9 documentation on cfmodule](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1912c-7fce.html).

This template/module however will only have access to a handful of scopes that the caller template has access to: request, session and application

Comment: In this case, `cfmodule` adds unnecessary complexity: the OP would have to pass name and age as arguments. With `cfinclude`, there's no need to do so.