# CFinclude issue

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to cfinclude a file and also pass some values to that specific file. I don't know if it is possible so any reply is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
<cfoutput>

    <cfset path = "?id=#email_id#&contactid=#email_contactid#&ownerid=#email_ownerid#">

    <cfinclude template="/email_results#path#">

</cfoutput>
```

My mapping goes something like this:

> E:\sites\exampleCom\cf_modules\reports\resultsTemplate.cfm

I did a #expandPath("/email_results#path#")# and it is giving me the correct output

> (E:\sites\exampleCom\cf_modules\reports\resultsTemplate.cfm?id=123&contactid=123&ownerid=123)

but when I am trying to include the file it bugs out. Can I pass in variables through the cfinclude? Is this what it bugs out my code?

Comment: Here is a similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721079/passing-variables-to-cfinclude

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you do not pass variables to an include page. The include will be execute in the same context, so it can directly see the `email_id` and other variables.

Comment: I thought about it after I wrote the question that this might be the issue. I am re-writing my code now