# coldfusion 9 audit trail

Tags: coldfusion, audit

I want to audit how many times a certain page is executed. I was hoping to add `<cfinclude template="audit.cfm">` to the end of the page and log simple data, like user, date, script name. 
Question: how do I pass a current script name into `<cfinclude>`?

I am using CF9 and application.cfm. I thought I can add code to onSessionEnd(), but I don't think it will work. Here is my onSessionEnd() and onRequestEnd()

```
<cffunction name="onSessionEnd">
    <cfset SESSION.session_time = TimeFormat(Now() - SessionScope.started, "H:mm:ss")> <=== want to do this!!!
    <cfset structClear(SESSION)> <=== currently in place
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onRequestEnd">
    <cfif NOT isDefined("URL.contentonly")>
    <p align="right">
    <cfoutput>
        <font size="2" face="sans-serif" color="black">
        <i>&copy;#Year(Now())# Seattle Pacific Industries Inc</i><BR>
    </cfoutput>
    </p>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721079/passing-variables-to-cfinclude

Comment: (Update) AFAIK, you can't, directly (only throughput 'variables').  Though you could create a custom tag, which would support arbitrary attributes (script, user, etc....). Though why not include the logic inside OnRequest() instead? It will have access to the requested script and current session variables.

Comment: "Though why not include the logic inside OnRequest() instead?" << This. I wouldn't do this in a `cfinclude`. There are much better routes to handle this.

Comment: Could you post and example of how to use onRequestEnd() to store/audit usage data?

Comment: `onRequestEnd()` is a special method in ColdFusion that runs after every page request. No need to include any files. See the docs here - https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/onrequestend.html

Comment: How is it different? It has <cfinclude ...> in it.

Comment: "This. I wouldn't do this in a cfinclude..." Heh.. agreed. Bad choice of words. I didn't mean a *literal* CF include, more like handle ;-)  @user1549571 - They're talking about the OnRequestEnd function in general. It doesn't *have to* use cfinclude. It's probably better not to. You can place the audit code (query, logging, cfc call, etc..) inside directly the function, no CFinclude needed.

Comment: how do I get a list of all session variables available to me?

Comment: `<cfdump var="#session#">`

Comment: Also, what version of ColdFusion are you using? And are you using `Application.cfc` or `Application.cfm`?

Comment: I am using CF9 and Application.cfc

Comment: I think i can get most of the session.* variables, but struggling with time it takes to run the page. I wanted to place `<cfset SESSION.session_time = TimeFormat(Now() - SessionScope.started, "H:mm:ss")>` into onSessionEnd(), but I have this line in there, which will kill it `<cfset structClear(SESSION)>`

Comment: Take another look at the documentation.  The function signatures are wrong. They must have the same name, returntype, number of arguments, etc... as shown in the docs: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/method-summary.html . For example OnRequestEnd is missing argument "targetPage"